# How do I install .tar.bz files?

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

I am a Linux beginner. I have installed Linux Mint. The network connection is not working (neither wired nor wireless). I downloaded a file for the wireless driver "broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0.tar.bz2"
and now I want to install hoping that my wireless will work. How can I install that file without using internet ? If there is any other way to make my Network work (wireless and wired), please share. My Network shows "Networking disabled"

Comment: You need to extract the files from the archive you downloaded.  Most Linux based operating systems have a `tar` command that can be used in a situation like this.

Comment: What you are doing should not be necessary, the broadcom drivers should be included with Mint. Please open a terminal run `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` and add the output to your question.

Comment: IN fact, even better, ask a new question about how to configure network access in Mint and put the information there.

Answer (score 2):

It's an archive file. Extract it from the terminal with:

```
tar -xjf broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0.tar.bz2
```

Then browse to the extracted files. I think you will find a README file that explains how to install the driver.

A guide is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1044898.html) - it's for Ubuntu but might work for Linuxmint - give it a shot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The general convention for installing from .tar.bz files is:

1. Extract the file:

   ```
   tar -xvfj filename.tar.bz
   ```
2. Enter the folder:

   ```
   cd filename
   ```
3. Configure the build script:

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
4. Build the software:

   ```
   make
   ```
5. Install the software:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Note that this is only a convention, some software may have slightly or even completely different steps. Also, you'll (usually) need gcc, etc. installed, which may be tricky if you don't have Internet on the box.